# access list from query result on django(python)

Tags: python, django

```
DB table
select * from AAA;

id |  name  | grade
--------------------
 1 |  john  | A
 2 |  cavin | B
```

django

```
grade_list = AAA.objects.all()
for item in grade_list:
    print item.name
```

result ->

```
john
cavin
```

============================================

I want to change this code(same function)

```
grade_list = AAA.objects.all()
print_field = 'name'

for item in grade_list:
    print item.(  print_field...  )
```

result ->

```
john
cavin
```

Q) fill in the blank please. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this with the `getattr` built-in function.

```
grade_list = AAA.objects.all()
print_field = 'name'

for item in grade_list:
    print getattr(item, print_field)
```

Comment: er, think you mean `getattr(item, print_field)`.