# django make query

Tags: python, django

DB TABLE

```
select * from AAA;
id   |    Name     |    Class  | Grade    |
--------------------------------------
1    |     john    |      1    |   A      |
2    |     Jane    |      2    |   B      |
3    |     Joon    |      2    |   A      |
4    |     Josh    |      3    |   C      |
```

|

Code

```
Django
search_result = AAA.objects.filter(Grade = 'B').count() 
print search_result
```

search_result -> 2

I want to change Grade to Class by VALUE.

```
Django
target_filter = 'Class'
search_result = AAA.objects.filter(__"target_filter..."__ = '3').count()
```

search_result -> 1

Q) How can I complete this code? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can shorten aeby's example by putting the kwargs in directly

```
target_filter = 'Class'
search_result = AAA.objects.filter(**{target_filter:3}).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
target_filter = 'Class'
filter_args = {target_filter: 3}
search_result = AAA.objects.filter(**filter_args).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is somehow the same answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645149/access-list-from-query-result-on-djangopython/7645210#7645210). You can also use the `getattr` but now with the module object itself. This is either `__module__` if it is the same module, or the module you `import`ed.

```
target_filter = 'Class'
search_result = AAA.objects.filter(getattr(__module__, target_filter) = '3').count()
```

---

**EDIT:** I got it wrong, it is not possible to access the current module via `__module__`. If the class is declared in the same module as your search, you can use `globals()[target_filter]` to access it. If your search is from another module, you can do it like this:

```
import somemodule

...

target_filter = 'Class'
search_result = AAA.objects.filter(getattr(somemodule, target_filter) = '3').count()
```